# Non-identified algorithm for RSA decryption in tpm-emulator

Tags: rsa, decryption, c, algorithm, tpm

While analyzing the source code of [`tpm-emulator`](https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator) I found that the RSA key decryption uses an algorithm that is unknown to me.

The original file with this mystery is located [in `rsa.c`](https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator/blob/master/crypto/rsa.c), where the `rsa_private(...)` function resides. The shortened content of this function is the following:

```
static int rsa_private(tpm_rsa_private_key_t *key,
                       const uint8_t *in, size_t in_len, uint8_t *out)
{
  ...
  if (!key->p || !key->q || !key->u) {
    /* c = p ^ d mod n */
    tpm_bn_powm(c, p, key->d, key->n);
  } else {
    tpm_bn_init2(m1, key->size / 2);
    tpm_bn_init2(m2, key->size / 2);
    tpm_bn_init2(h, key->size);
    /* m1 = p ^ (d mod (p-1)) mod p */
    tpm_bn_sub_ui(h, key->p, 1);
    tpm_bn_mod(h, key->d, h);
    tpm_bn_powm(m1, p, h, key->p);
    /* m2 = p ^ (d mod (q-1)) mod q */
    tpm_bn_sub_ui(h, key->q, 1);
    tpm_bn_mod(h, key->d, h);
    tpm_bn_powm(m2, p, h, key->q);
    /* h = u * ( m2 - m1 ) mod q */
    tpm_bn_sub(h, m2, m1);
    if (tpm_bn_sgn(h) < 0) tpm_bn_add(h, h, key->q);
    tpm_bn_mul(h, key->u, h);
    tpm_bn_mod(h, h, key->q);
    /* c = m1 + h * p */
    tpm_bn_mul(h, h, key->p);
    tpm_bn_add(c, m1, h);
    tpm_bn_clear(m1);
    tpm_bn_clear(m2);
    tpm_bn_clear(h);
  }
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

The basic idea of this function is to decrypt input message `in` (`p` in a formula) of size `in_len` with the help of private RSA key `key` (exponent is `d` and modulus is `n`).

While this part of the code (1st algorithm of decryption):

```
/* c = p ^ d mod n */
```

is clear, the other possible algorithm of the decryption code is a mystery to me:

```
/* m1 = p ^ (d mod (p-1)) mod p */
/* m2 = p ^ (d mod (q-1)) mod q */
/* h = u * ( m2 - m1 ) mod q */
/* c = m1 + h * p */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the aim to speed up the RSA decryption process, sometimes, "Chinese Remainder Theorem" is used. The theory with the practice about the usage of this theorem may be found in the article ["Using the CRT with RSA"](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/crt_rsa.html).